# Json schema with common data type

Tags: json

I have a scenario to add "null" to all the properties in a JSON schema
for eg. currently my JSON schema looks like this

```
{
    "field1": {
        "type": ["string", "null"]
    },
    "field2: {
        "type": ["number", "null"]
    },
    "field3": {
        "type": ["boolean", "null"]
    },
    "field4": {
        "type": ["array", "null"]
    }
}
```

Is it possible to add null in a common place in the JSON Schema so that all the fields will accept null value plus their data type

Answer (score 2):

JSON just a data format, so what is mean is defined by yourself.

if you want "null" in common place, and all fields type contain it, you must modify the program in order to understand the new JSON format